# Cómo obtener el valor checked de un MenuItem en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Necesito obtener si un item del ménu principal de mi App está selecionado o no.

Mi menú

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/miCompose"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_center_focus_strong_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/select_scope"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_scope_word"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:checked="true"
                android:title="@string/word" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_scope_line"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="@string/line" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_scope_text"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:title="@string/text" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Me gustaría obtener en cualquier parte si `action_scope_line` si está seleccionado.

Lo siguiente no me funciona

```
MenuItem checkBox = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_scope_line);

if (checkBox != null) if (checkBox.isChecked()) //checkeado
```

> checkBox es nulo me indica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtenerlo mediante el id, en el método `onOptionsItemSelected()` :

```
    Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     boolean miValor;
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_check) {
            miValor = item.isChecked());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
 super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Si dentro del método onOptionsItemSelected y onOptionsItemPrepared es donde no tengo problemas en acceder a un  menuiitem en concreto, fuera de ellos no ser como referirme, lo que quiero realizar lo puedo comprobar en estos dos métodos y guardar en una variable global.